# Gorm issue help

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two classes

```
class Facebook {
   String fid
   String name
   User user
   static constraints = {
       user(nullable:false)
   }
}
```

and

```
class User {
   Facebook facebook
   String fullname
}
```

I make a Facebook object , then make a User object and when I try to save User it does not 
allow me to . The error comes like

```
Trying to marshall a null id [id] for alias [User]
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check how to setup a one-to-one mapping with Grails GORM following this link:

[http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.2.1.1 Many-to-one and one-to-one](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.2.1.1%20Many-to-one%20and%20one-to-one)

There is an example with Face and Nose similar to User/Facebook.

Comment: -1.  This answer really isn't helpful.  Please explain what the op did wrong.